# curl type and ruby rest client

Tags: ruby, json, curl, rest-client

I am not able to translate the curl command into ruby rest-client

`curl 'http://localhost:8080/../attachments' -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "CMD-Authorization: xxxx" -X POST -F attachment='{"_description":"this is test";type=application/json' -F file=@/root/Desktop/rest/saturn.bin`

The main problem regards the "**type=application/json**" in the form **attachment**.

My code is:

```
require 'base64'
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
....
file1=File.new('/root/Desktop/rest/saturn.bin','rb')
response =RestClient.post("#{uri}",
{
:attachment=>'{"_description":"this is test";"type"=>"application/json"}',
:file=>file1,
},{:cmd_authorization=>"#{@session_id}"})`
```

I tried other code combination adding for example :content_type=>"application/json" in the header unsuccessfully. Thanks for the support.